# Typescript Class Decorator Executing Class Instance Method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

First, I'm aware that Decorators are executed when the class is constructed. I'm looking for advice on getting around that restriction.

Second, I had previously attempted a different approach.

With that said, here's my issue. I am attempting to create a Typescript decorator to force a decorated class to execute an instance method named `onLogin()` based on a subscription to an RXJS observable.

Here is the code, as is:

```js
export function LoginAware() {

    return function (target: any): void {

        const loginFunctionName : string = "onLogin";
        const className: string = target.name || target.toString().match(/\w+/g);

        // timeout ensures that the UtilityService injector is populated
        setTimeout(() => {

            const injector: Injector = UtilityService.injector;
            if (!injector) {
                return;
            }

            const authService: AuthService = injector.get(AuthService);
            const logger: NGXLogger = injector.get(NGXLogger);
            const destroyRef: DestroyRef = injector.get(DestroyRef);

            if (authService) {

                const login$ = authService.login$
                    .pipe(
                        tap(() => target[loginFunctionName]()), // works with static methods, but not instance methods
                        takeUntilDestroyed(destroyRef)
                    )
                    .subscribe();

                destroyRef.onDestroy(() => {
                    login$.unsubscribe();
                });

            } else {
                logger.warn(`Unable to inject AuthService into ${className}`);
            }



        });


        return target;
    }
}
```

I don't need to execute the onLogin() method when the decorator executes. I'm looking for a way that the subscribed Observable can execute that method later.

This works with static methods, but unfortunately, I need to access instance methods. For example, when the user logs in, the Employee service may need to access an external API to get a list of all of the employees that the current user manages.

Can anyone suggest an approach that will allow my observables in the decorate to execute instance methods?

Comment: "*I need to access instance methods.*" - where would you get the instance from? Or: where are the instances created that you want to use?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. I'm looking for an idea because the instance doesn't have to exist when the decorator initially executes, only when the Observable in AuthService imits.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that your decorator should not be responsible for creating the instance(s). Do that somewhere else in your program (or just as a separate decorator that makes use of Angular's dependency injection mechanisms, which I have no knowledge of)

Answer (score 1):

The decorator function support more than one parameter.

```
target: unknown,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>,
```

The important one, is the third one.

Find below a method i wrote for logging, hopefully it is helpful:

```
function log(
  target: unknown,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>,
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function (...args: unknown[]) {
    console.log(`The method ${propertyKey} args are: `, args);
    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    console.log('The return value is: ', result);
    return result;
  };
  return descriptor;
}
```

The important part is, that you overwrite the method:

```
descriptor.value = function (...args: unknown[]) {
... do something
call the original
... do something
```

...